# preventing postgresql commands from keep asking for user password

Tags: linux, postgresql, shell

It's strange, but i've searched around for this source of configuration but couldnt find it out.

Im currently using opensuse 11.3 with postgresql 9.

Every postgresql command line that i issue will ask the current user password, like psql, createdb, dropdb, and i have to enter the password of the current user (which is postgres) to make it work.

Doing `dropdb xxx && createdb xxx` will ask the password twice.

Please show me the light !

Thank you :-)

---

### EDIT

Actually im already running as a postgres user (a user in my linux), so i can psql without supplying the database password, but i still have to supply the password for the system user postgres.

So if the database has a user of dbuser, and im running psql as the postgres (linux user), a password for the linux user (postgres) will be asked, not the dbuser password.

Answer (score 8):

You can create a `~/.pgpass` file (`%APPDATA%\postgresql\pgpass.conf` on Windows) with a line in the following format:

```
hostname:port:database:username:password
```

See [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-pgpass.html) for details.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I've updated the original post adding more clarity at the bottom part.

Comment: The default port number is 5432.

Answer (score 3):

If you're on opensuse you should be able to create a .pgpass file by running:

```
echo "hostname:port:database:username:password" > ~/.pgpass
chmod 0600 ~/.pgpass
```

With all of the correct information of course.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I've updated the original post adding more clarity at the bottom part.

Answer (score 3):

if you have a `.pgpass` file setup to allow a certain user access to a certain database (let's call it "myprojectdb"), recall that `creatdb` and `dropdb` aren't really acting on "myprojectdb" despite the fact that you may be asking them to create and drop that db.

You'll most likely want to add postgres' internal tables to your `pgpass` permissions  (postgres / templates).  Also don't forget to add the `--no-password` option on both `createdb` and `dropdb` to ignore interactive prompts (note this will only work if the user specified with the `-U` option can modify the internal postgres tables)